# jQuery typing script

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

Simple piece of jQuery that adds the class `.typing` to the `<html>` tag while the user is currently typing. I've tried several different things that all haven't worked, not sure how else to do this.

```
$('html').keypress(function(){
    $(this).addClass('typing');

    if  ( /* No key is pressed again in the next 0.5 seconds */ ) {
        $('.typing').removeClass('typing');
    }
});
```

Comment: please specify what are you actually asking - is it about implenting the condition after the if or is it why this script isn't working for you (document.ready stuff etc)?

Comment: the answer below already fixes this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a function which executes certain code after 0.5 seconds, using `setTimeout` (in conjunction with `clearTimeout`, to prevent multiple timeouts from be active at a time).

```
var timer;                  //Local variable to hold time-out reference
function refreshPress(){
    clearTimeout(timer);    //Prevent stacked time-outs, only one is allowed
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        $('.typing').removeClass('typing');
    }, 500); //0.5 seconds
}

$('html').keypress(function(){
    $(this).addClass('typing');  //This line can also be merged with refreshPress
    refreshPress();              // Call refreshPress
});
```

Comment: actually now that I try it out, after a couple of times typing it stops using the delay and just immediately add and removes it

Comment: @JamesKyle Show a fiddle with your code. Have you correctly implemented the code in the answer?

Comment: @JamesKyle You were missing `timer = `. Fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UDhfU/31/

Answer (score 1):

Use setTimeout() and clearTimeout() instead of the if.